# SQL query does not work when executing from Rails console

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to run the following line in my Rails console:

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "DELETE FROM recommendations WHERE place_id=4000000001267 AND recommender_id=2728498;UPDATE IGNORE recommendations SET place_id=4000000001267 WHERE place_id=4000000564630 AND recommender_id=2728498;"`

It is simply deleting an old record and rewriting another record for merging purposes.

Rails console returns the following:

`DELETE FROM recommendations WHERE place_id=4000000001267 AND recommender_id=2728498;UPDATE IGNORE recommendations SET place_id=4000000001267 WHERE place_id=4000000564630 AND recommender_id=2728498;
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE IGNORE recommendations SET place_id=4000000001267 WHERE place_id=40000005' at line 1: DELETE FROM recommendations WHERE place_id=4000000001267 AND recommender_id=2728498;UPDATE IGNORE recommendations SET place_id=4000000001267 WHERE place_id=4000000564630 AND recommender_id=2728498;
from /Users/huynguyen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:243:in`query'`

However, when I run this exact query in Sequel Pro, the query runs perfectly fine. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: @Greg To ignore any errors and continue since I'll be running multiple queries.

Comment: I encountered something similar in the past, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127980/rails-3-possible-erb-bug-when-executing-raw-sql-calling-scopes still never reached a definitive answer, but my best guess is that there's some SQL translation going on when the server is running to better match SQL to the vendor.

Comment: @CyleHunter I had to change my code to do two queries. See answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might it be connected to the fact AR's mysql adapter doesn't have multiple query execution on by default?

A quick fix for this would be splitting the query into two distinct and execute them one after another. And wrapping them into a transaction, of course :)